# I'm trying to load my cog through 3 folders, however, it doesnt seem to work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, operating-system, listdir

My directory goes like this:
bob (folder) -> main (folder) -> commands (folder) -> test (folder) test.py (file)

This code seems to work fine

```
async def load1():
    for filename in os.listdir("main/commands"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"commands.{filename[:-3]}")
```

but i want my code to go through another folder
like this

```
async def load1():
    for filename in os.listdir("main/commands/testfolder"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"testfolder.{filename[:-3]}")
```

when i run this, it gives me the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfolder'`

Basically, i want my code to load folders which would contain something like this
commandFolder -> command.py, command.json, command.txt

### Is this possible?

Comment: To load `/commands` your argument starts with `commands.`, but to load `/commands/testfolder` your argument is `testfolder.`. How is `load_extension` supposed to know where `testfolder` is located? You should pass the whole path to reach it, being `commands.testfolder`. Note that all of these folders need an `__init__.py` file inside of them.

Comment: On another note - why do you have a json file & a text file for every single command?